# Display a PostgreSQL view in odoo 12

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I have the following table:

```
select id, time from attendance ;
```

> ```
>  device_id  |    punching_time 
> ---------- -+---------------------
>      1      | 2019-11-20 15:37:00
>      2      | 2019-11-20 15:50:07
>      3      | 2019-11-20 15:51:47
> ```

How do I display a PostgreSQL view  in Odoo 12 as a Tree view? How do I create the Python class for it?

Comment: Check [How do I display a PostgreSQL view in Odoo as a Tree view?](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-do-i-display-a-postgresql-view-ie-create-view-as-in-odoo-as-a-tree-view-how-do-i-create-the-python-class-for-it-108041)